# Could 2 collided neutron stars partialy lose mass?

Tags: black-holes, gravitational-waves, mass-energy, neutron-stars

If two collided black holes lose a huge part of their masses before collision do a pair of neutron stars lose such quantity of mass and is the density of an astronomical body the cause of how much of the mass will be destroyed on collision?

Comment: Neutron stars also lose mass during merger via gravitational waves just like Black Holes. Neutron stars mergers also produce gamma rays bursts as well as rare heavy elements like gold.

Comment: @Pagoda If the collision is not direct smasing but a rotational approaching can the radius of the new neutron star be measured to figure out if there has really some mass gone by grav. waves?

Comment: Rotational approach would mean orbital energy creating gravitational waves. This might answer your question: https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.11581